# Hiding data on Parse Default ashboard

Tags: ios

How can I hide fields content in the dashboard?
For example, I have a field called *messages* and I want hide this field's content in my dashboard:

```
╔═══════════════════════════╗
║    userid        2216     ║
╠═══════════════════════════╣
║ messages           hidden ║
╚═══════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: What control you are using?

Comment: I am using ParseFramework for storing data in parse dashboard